# Create a vertical fast scrolling menu web

Tags: canvas, web, webgl

Lets say I control this menu of a 100 items, with the up and down keys. They should scroll up/down the screen like an AppleTV scrolls. Fast and smooth.

How would I implement this for web a webpage/Android WebView(ChromeView)?
Canvas WebGl? Any pointers are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using: https://github.com/PixelsCommander/HTML-GL
Tried: http://www.pixijs.com/ but was a bit more complex.